# Tooltip background color in d3 is only filling half

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

I am trying to apply background color to d3 tooltip but it only fills top half square of tooltip area as shown in image below:

[image]

Here is my code for it:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .style("background",'#BCC5F7');
```

Tooltip example from http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-tooltips-to-d3js-graph.html

Comment: How are you using the tooltip? What's the CSS for it?

Comment: updated link to tooltip. Thanks for the pointer, I fixed it by changing CSS.

Comment: Ok, so your question is solved?

Comment: Yes it is solved now.

Comment: Would you mind posting the answer then please?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at it the wrong way. I was trying to fix it via changing js rather than CSS.

```
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 78px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

I had above css code where changing the height attribute fixed the issue.